# add label with case when by using timerange with spark sql?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, case-when

I have this table where shows ID and also timestamp. I want to add label for each timestamp range.

```
ID          timestamp
a       2020-01-16 08:55:50
b       2020-01-16 08:57:37
c       2020-01-16 09:00:13
d       2020-01-16 09:01:32
e       2020-01-16 09:03:32
f       2020-01-16 09:06:56
```

for example, from 2020-01-16 08:55:50 to 2020-01-16 09:00:13 is X, and from 2020-01-16 09:01:32 to 2020-01-16 09:06:56 is Y.

I expect the table will show:

```
ID        timestamp                type_flag
a       2020-01-16 08:55:50          X
b       2020-01-16 08:57:37          X
c       2020-01-16 09:00:13          X
d       2020-01-16 09:01:32          Y
e       2020-01-16 09:03:32          Y
f       2020-01-16 09:06:56          Y
g       2020-01-16 09:08:51          Z
h       2020-01-16 09:10:43          Z
i       2020-01-16 09:13:21          Z
```

so far, what I have tried:

```
SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN timestamp BETWEEN '2020-01-16 08:55:50' AND '2020-01-16 09:00:13' THEN 'X' 
         WHEN timestamp BETWEEN '2020-01-16 09:01:32' and '2020-01-16 09:06:56' THEN 'Y'
         WHEN timestamp BETWEEN '2020-01-16 09:08:51' and '2020-01-16 09:13:21' THEN 'Z'
    ELSE 'A' END AS type_flag
FROM table1;
```

but it gave me an error saying:

```
Error [22P02]: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "2021-01-16 08:55:50"
  Position: 37
```

How should I fix my query to get my desired result? I use spark sql for this

Thanks.

Comment: try wrapping the time strings in `timestamp()`? Like `between timestamp('2020-01-16 08:55:50') and ...`

Comment: I tried, but it got an error as well saying ```Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "'2021-01-16 08:55:50'"
  Position: 50```

Comment: you probably got a syntax error somewhere else, like a missing parenthesis or comma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is something wrong with your syntax or how you are doing your transformation.

```
//creating sample data
val df = Seq(("a","2020-01-16 08:55:50"),("b","2020-01-16 08:57:37"),("c","2020-01-16 09:00:13"),("d","2020-01-16 09:01:32"),("e","2020-01-16 09:03:32"),("f","2020-01-16 09:06:56")).toDF("ID","timestamp")
//changing the data type of the timestamp column from string to timestamp
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val df1 = df.withColumn("timestamp",$"timestamp".cast("TimeStamp"))
//creating a view so that I can query it using spark sql
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("timestamptest")
//case when statements inside the spark sql
val df3 = spark.sql("""select *, CASE WHEN timestamp BETWEEN '2020-01-16 08:55:50' AND '2020-01-16 09:00:13' THEN 'X' 
         WHEN timestamp BETWEEN '2020-01-16 09:01:32' and '2020-01-16 09:06:56' THEN 'Y'
         WHEN timestamp BETWEEN '2020-01-16 09:08:51' and '2020-01-16 09:13:21' THEN 'Z'
    ELSE 'A' END As type_flag from timestamptest""")
display(df3)
```

You can see the output as below :

[image]